# What is the scalar product used for?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been confusing the scalar product with the orthogonal projection and now that I've learned they are they are different: what exactly is the scalar product used for?

It seems ridiculous to defined it just to simplify a multiplication when calculating work etc.

Comment: The scalar product is the most common calculational tool for finding the algebraic expression for an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Precisely, for any unit vector $n$ and any other vector $v$, $v \cdot n$ is the component of $v$ in the $n$-direction. This idea is generalized to the notion of abstract inner product spaces which are quite useful for in many settings. Fourier analysis comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general vector space the scalar product is essentially how you calculate the lengths of vectors and the angles between vectors, and it is what lets you do orthogonal projections in the first place. Without it you can't compare lengths of vectors that aren't in the same line, and you can't tell whether or not two vectors are orthogonal.

Even in Euclidean space where introductions to vector concepts generally define the scalar product from geometry, rather than geometry from the scalar product, the scalar product is very useful. It measures "how much are these two vectors in the same direction as each other" much more efficiently than projecting one onto the other and comparing the lengths of the projections.

Edit:

As an example of the usefulness of the scalar product, the equations of General Relativity essentially solve for the scalar product on the tangent vector spaces at every point in the space-time manifold, and the scalar product (and how it varies from point to point) is used to tell us everything about how matter and energy affects the curvature of space-time. So in GR the geometry of space-time comes out of the scalar product rather than vice versa.

Comment: Very good points. To high-light that geometry comes from a scalarproduct, one might add that in general there are various different scalar product on one space and each gives rise to its own geometry (including orthogonal projections).